# Law of Total Probability - Why do these form a partition?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a biased coin, where the probability of getting a head is $p$, with all tosses being mutually independent. Let $H_n$ be the event that on the $n^{th}$ toss we have an even number of heads, and let $p_n=Pr(H_n)$.
Show, by using the law of total probability, that $p_n = (1 − 2p)p_{n−1} + p$.

I've managed to get this using my partitioning events as $A_1$ = odd number of heads on the $(n-1)^{th}$ toss and $A_2$ = even number of heads on the $(n-1)^{th}$ toss. These events are certainly disjoint, but I'm unsure as to how their union is the sample space.

My question: What is the sample space? Does the sample space change after every head and is just what you could have achieved thus far at each toss (e.g on the 3rd toss your sample space is $(TTT, TTH, THH, HHH)$)? And if that's the case, don't $A_1$ and $A_2$ partition a sample space that is no longer applicable as we're now talking about the sample space for this toss, whereas those events are talking about that for the previous?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a subscripting error in the formula you wrote above, you're likely supposed to show that 
$$
p_n = (1-2p)p_{n-1} + p \neq (1-2p)p_n - 1 + p
$$
Working under this correction, I suggest a "first step analysis" approach:
$$
p_n = \mathbb{P}(H_n) = \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(H_n \mid 1st=H)}_{1-p_{n-1}}\mathbb{P}(1st = H) + \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(H_n \mid 1st = T)}_{p_{n-1}} \mathbb{P}(1st = T) = \cdots
$$
I'll let you think about why the values I assigned to the underbrace are correct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error with the subscript.

Comment: I understand your approach, thank you for sharing it, however do you have an answer as to what the sample space is in this situation?

Comment: @hhattiecc The sample space is generated by a *potentially* infinite sequence of independent coin tosses, thus $\{\mathrm T, \mathrm H\}^\infty$ is reasonable; although, of course, we are only *really* ever interested in the finite subset generated by some earliest consecutive tosses.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks for the response Graham. My confusion lies with that if the sample space is the potentially infinite sequence of independent coin tosses, can I not use the number of heads being even or odd on the $(n-1)^{th}$ toss as a partition? Whereas the approach given above by Tom avoids this, as there are only two possibilities for _any_ given sequence: tails or heads on the first toss.

Comment: @hhattiecc Do you mean as in the following? Partitioning on the event of the first $n-1$ tosses having even or odd count of heads gives: $$\mathsf P(H_n)=\mathsf P(H_{n-1})~\mathsf P(H_n\mid H_{n-1})+\mathsf P(H_{n-1}^\complement)~\mathsf P(H_n\mid H_{n-1}^\complement)$$  Which is essentially the same as Tom's result due to the *independent and identical distribution* of the coin flips.